# Change text file case and copy data in C

Tags: c, text-files

I am creating a program which copies text file data from one file and changes its case to lower or upper on choice, but when I execute the program I receive the following result and the text case is not changed or copied.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {

             FILE *fp  = NULL;
            FILE *fp2 = NULL;
            char str[200];
            char var;
            int i;
            char copy;



            fp = fopen("file1.txt", "a");
            fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "w");

            printf("Enter choice: ");
            scanf(" %c", &var);

            if (fp != NULL && var == 'L') {

                    while ( fgets(str, 200, fp) != NULL ) {

                            putchar(tolower(fp[i]));
                            i++;
                    }

                    puts(str);
            }
            else if (fp != NULL && var == 'U') {

                    while ( fgets(str, 200, fp) != NULL ) {

                            putchar(toupper(fp[i]));
                            i++;
                    }

                    puts(str);
            }
            else {

                    printf("ERROR: No proper choice was made \n");
            }
    while (1) {

                copy = fgetc(fp);

                if (copy == EOF) {

                        break;
                }
                else {

                        putc(copy , fp2);
                }
        }

        return 0;

        fclose(fp);
        fclose(fp2);

}
```

The output I get is:

```
    Enter choice: U
▒▒
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putchar(tolower(fp[i]));` should have generated compiler warnings.  Insure the compiler warning are all enabled or consider a new compiler.

Replace in 2 places, both upper and lower section.

```
while ( fgets(str, 200, fp) != NULL ) {
   putchar(tolower(fp[i]));
   i++;
}

// With to iterate over each character
while (fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) != NULL) {
  for (i=0; str[i]; i++) {
    putchar(tolower(str[i]));
  }
}
```

Change to `int` to properly distinguish all characters returned from `fgetc()` from `EOF`.

Open with "r" to read from the beginning of the file

```
// fp = fopen("file1.txt", "a")
fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `fgets`, which reads a string from the file. A better way of doing this would be to use `fgetc`, which reads just one character at a time and process it appropiately.